# Cannot custom Actionbar's navigate up method

Tags: android, android-actionbar, kotlin

In the activity class, I set up the actionbar as this:

**MyActivity**

```
setSupportActionBar(findViewById(R.id.toolbar_my))
    supportActionBar?.apply {
        setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true)
        setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true)
    }
```

Because I need to override `onOptionsItemSelected(...)` (in the fragment class), I didn't override `onSupportNavigateUp()` here.
This activity cotnains a fragment. What I want is, when click on the actionbar up button, besides pop back, also revoke a custom save() method.

So in the fragment's `onOptionsItemSelected(...)`, write some code for the `item.id == android.R.id.home` case. However, I made a break point here, and found that when click on the up/home button, the code in the `android.R.id.home` case is never revoked. The other items' on selected methods work.

In the fragment class:

**MyFragment**

```
    override fun onOptionsItemSelected(item: MenuItem?): Boolean {

    when (item?.itemId) {
        android.R.id.home -> { 
// code here not gets called when click up/home button
            mPresenter.save()
            return true
        }

        R.id.edit-> {
            // The code here is revoked when item selected.
        }

        else -> {
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item)
        }
    }
}
```

I tried override another `onOptionsItemSelected(...)` method in the activity class, and write `android.R.id.home` case, still cannot invoke methods in it.

Why the code in `item.id == android.R.id.home` case is not called?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Read [**`setHomeButtonEnabled`**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActionBar.html#setHomeButtonEnabled(boolean))

> Enable or disable the "home" button in the corner of the action bar.
>   (Note that this is the application home/up affordance on the action
>   bar, not the systemwide home button.)

```
 supportActionBar?.setHomeButtonEnabled(true)
 supportActionBar?.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true)
```

Then

```
override fun onOptionsItemSelected(item: MenuItem): Boolean {
    when (item.getItemId()){
        android.R.id.home -> {
            mPresenter.save()
            return true
        }
         R.id.edit-> {
            // some code
        }
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item)
}
```

Comment: To my understanding, is this still my code but change MenuItem? type to MenuType type? I tried it, still not work.

Comment: @Robin okay. At first enable `setHomeButtonEnabled` in your code

Comment: Sorry my fault, it still not work. The problem is, when click on up/home button, it just never falls into the `android.R.id.home`  case.